# Interruptible, incremental backup tool with timing strategies

Tags: backup, scheduled-task, incremental-backup

Basically, I'm searching for a rdiff-backup that can be safely interrupted (network disconnection, computer switch off, sleep), and that can develop scheduling strategies to in order to avoid interruptions (nonetheless).

Scheduling strategies would analyze computer boot and shutdown to extract patterns, to start the backups at times where the computer will be likely awake enough for the backup to complete, and maybe extract usage pattern and avoid intense usage periods (like the minutes after the boot completed).

This is complex software, and with a solution that wont be perfect, but i wonder if something like this exists, or if a combination of tools (rdiff-backup + statistical scheduling) could lead me to something similar.

Comment: This seems like a very narrow use for a backup solution. The requirements are too specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there's an off the shelf solution out there. If you're willing to write some code you might be able to adapt an existing tool.

[BackpPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/faq/BackupPC.html#what_to_backup_and_when_to_do_it) has some interesting options for scheduling backups. I've never used it but have heard good things. Its bigger and more complex than rdiff-backup but it might be an option for you.

As for your requriements:

> can be safely interrupted (network disconnection, computer switch off, sleep)

You could try combining [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) with some alternative cron like [fcron](http://fcron.free.fr/description.php) which is cron designed for computers not up 24/7 so you can be sure a 'daily' cron job will be run once a day even if the computer isn't up when the 'cron.daily' jobs are normally run.

> that can develop scheduling strategies to in order to avoid interruptions (nonetheless)

You could write script to keep track of stuff like this, which could then modify the cron job for your backup so it will run in the desired time frame.

fcron also has some options about running only when something is below a certain load.

Comment: Thanks for the great informations, that will give me a good start.